# JunOS: How to copy the config file to TFTP server?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, tftp

Model: j6350

JUNOS Software Release [12.1X46-D65.4]

Is there an easy way to copy the config file to TFTP?

Comment: Is there any compelling reason to not use SCP instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JunOS has a tftp client available from the shell.  You can use it as follows:

```
jsw@router> start shell 
% cd /config
% tftp
tftp> connect 192.0.2.69
tftp> put juniper.conf.gz
Sent 3896 bytes in 0.4 seconds
tftp> ^D% 
% exit
exit
```

A common reason for doing this is to back up your configuration.  Note JunOS can do this automatically via FTP, HTTP, or SCP if you configure it as follows ([Juniper guide](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/configuration/junos-software-system-management-router-configuration-archiving.html)):

```
system {
    archival {
        configuration {
            transfer-on-commit;
            archive-sites {
                "scp://user@host:/directory/ password foo";
            }
        }
    }
}
```